# JavaScript get TextArea input via .value or .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, textarea, innerhtml

Is it ok to get the value of a textarea element in JavaScript with `myTextArea.value` or should I use `myTextArea.innerHTML`?

Thank you.

Comment: Being form element, `value` is the proper way.

Comment: Please, for this kind of questions always point the spec, thanks: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-textarea-value

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You should use .value

```
myTextArea.value
```

Comment: Since textarea has an endtag <textarea></textarea>.I thought i have to use .innerHTML & .value won't work.I was setting textarea value in codebehind.Though innerHTML was giving me value but even though i edit the value ,it use to give me the same old value that i had setup from code behind.Read ur answer and used textarea.value.its working fine now.I'm getting textarea value properly now.up voted d ans.

Comment: Please, for this kind of questions always point the spec, thanks: html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-textarea-value

Answer (score 17):

One difference is that you can use HTML entities with .innerHTML

```js
document.getElementById('t1').innerHTML = '&lt;&gt;&amp;';
document.getElementById('t2').value = '&lt;&gt;&amp;';
```

```html
<textarea id="t1"></textarea>
<textarea id="t2"></textarea>
```

Comment: This question is about reading the value, not about setting it.

Answer (score 6):

For div and span, you can use innerHTML, but for textarea use value. Please see the example below.

```
<script language="javascript/text">
document.getElementById("spanText").innerHTML ="text";
document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML ="text";
document.getElementById("textArea").value ="text";
</script>


<span id="spanText"></span>
<div id="divText"></div>
<textarea id="textArea"></textArea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use innerHTML use value e.g. document.getElementById(name).value

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your situation.

I would personally use .value as that's what the other form inputs provide. It's easier to be in the habit of doing it that way.