# How can i output this content to a textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have tried to pass on the text from a php page into my html page, as described by Chris Bakers answer (javascript, not jquery).
[Call php function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

The code works, if i use the normal text (id=output), but i would like to output the text to a textarea (id=text1) instead of a normal text, just changing the id does not work.

This is my code:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <textarea id="text1" style="background-color: #969696" cols="50" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
 <div id="output">waiting for action</div>
 </body>
 <script>


    function getOutput() {
    var value = document.getElementById("artikelnr").value;
    var file = selectedValue()+".csv";
      getRequest(
          "verarbeitung.php?eingabe="+value+"&eingabe2="+file, // URL for the PHP file
           drawOutput,  // handle successful request
           drawError    // handle error
      );
      return false;
    }  
    // handles drawing an error message
    function drawError() {
        var container = document.getElementById('text1');
        container.innerHTML = 'Bummer: there was an error!';
    }
    // handles the response, adds the html
    function drawOutput(responseText) {
        var container = document.getElementById('text1');
        container.innerHTML = responseText;
    }
    // helper function for cross-browser request object
    function getRequest(url, success, error) {
        var req = false;
        try{
            // most browsers
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
            // IE
            try{
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                // try an older version
                try{
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch(e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!req) return false;
        if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
        if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4) {
                return req.status === 200 ? 
                    success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
            }
        }
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);
        return req;
    }


 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

**Reference:** [JavaScript get TextArea input via .value or .innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314186/javascript-get-textarea-input-via-value-or-innerhtml)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that works! 
But now it outputs the whole source code (e.g. <html> <body> etc.) is it possible to just output the text?

Comment: That would be another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: Thanks, i got it to work with the help of that question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not setInnerHtml, textarea has a value attribute. Not really logical but well...

mad you a fiddle:

```js
document.getElementById("bla").value = "test";
```

```html
<textarea id="bla" readonly >Initial Value</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks that works! 
But now it outputs the whole source code (e.g. <html> <body> etc.) is it possible to just output the text?