# JavaScript - Use innerHTML as actual html instead of plain text

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

When I'm trying to change `document.documentElement.innerHTML` using the `innerHTML` of a textarea like this:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#mytextarea').innerHTML
```

The `innerHTML` of `#mytextarea` is not used as actual HTML to change the DOM, but as plain text.

For example: if the `innerHTML` of `#mytextarea` is `<p>A paragraph</p>`.

Then the document after loading looks like: `<p>A paragraph</p>` instead of `A paragraph`

How should I do it so the value inside the `#mytextarea` could be used to change the DOM? (ex. appending new elements)

Comment: Please read the [help], especially [ask]. We generally want to see just the question and its related code/circumstances, not pleasantries or extra text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get TextArea input via .value or .innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314186/javascript-get-textarea-input-via-value-or-innerhtml)

Comment: What is `document.documentElement`?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement), the Document.documentElement read-only property returns the Element that is the root element of the document (for example, the <html> element for HTML documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value` to get the contents of a textarea without it being encoded.

```js
document.getElementById("documentElement").innerHTML = document.querySelector('#mytextarea').value;
```

```html
<textarea id="mytextarea">
<p>A paragraph</p>
</textarea>
<div id="documentElement">

</div>
```

Comment: @wirher Why do we need a jsfiddle when we have stack snippets?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was confused at first then realized I didn't update the value inside my textarea. My question was solved. (btw stackoverflow is very fast, I asked few minutes ago and there are answers instantly.)

Answer (score -4):

You can easily achieve this without the use of any JavaScript. You just have to insert special characters into your HTML code.

```
&lt;p&gt;A paragraph&lt;/p&gt;
```

That weird code will show up as

```
<p>A paragraph</p>
```

If you don't know the codes, just use this: [HTML Encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/htmlencode/encode.aspx)

EDIT:
They are called HTML escape characters, or, HTML entities. Here is a list of a lot of them: [List](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: @Juhana I thought that's what he was asking from this: "How should I do it so it would be used as actual HTML instead of plain text?"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I meant is to use a html string (for example: `"<img src='a.jpg' height='100' width='100'>"`) to change the DOM, if I use the string above, there would be a image in the document.