# How to set the textarea value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript code:

```js
var c=document.createElement("textarea");
c.value="what ever";
document.body.appendChild(c);
```

This supposed to add a textarea tag at the end of my page. The textarea is added, but it doesn't have the value set.

How can I solve that?

[image]

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/qpxy53ue/ as well as in the snippet in this page

Comment: because it is a property, it is not going to update the view source.

Comment: Don't know the reason, why it doesn't show the value attribute but It does update the value of Element. Event `Input` doesn't show the `value` in DOM if you add value from JS. But If you add element using HTML, It does show the attributes. `<textarea value="test"></textarea>` - It does shows

Comment: May be @epascarello right, Does it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Unclear why someone would need to see the value in the view source unless they are trying to clone elements with innerHTML....

Answer (score 3):

Use `innerHTML` to set the value of `textarea`.

```js
var c=document.createElement("textarea");
c.innerHTML="what ever";
document.body.appendChild(c);
```

Comment: Works fine with `value` which is preferred once in DOM

Comment: Although this is the correct answer (and works for most input-type tags), if you want to display a hint for the user, you should rather use the placeholder attribute.

Comment: you should consider to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314186/javascript-get-textarea-input-via-value-or-innerhtml) if you're going to use `innerHTML`. I don't think using `innerHTML` is not the right way to update the value